# Получения результата запроса от JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa

Возник вопрос с тем, как получить к примеру результат запроса, т.е. был ли он выполнен или нет.

Я так думал, что должно же исключение выбрасывать, если не работает запрос, но а какое я так и не нашел, да и вообще так кто-нибудь получает результат запроса через перехват исключения или нет? Сейчас все довольно примитивно и глупо так сказать.

**Вот пример:**

**`Entity`:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Group() {
    }

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**`Repository`:**

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {

    @Transactional
    void deleteByName(String name);

    @Transactional
    Group findByName(String name);

}
```

**`Service`:**

```
@Service
public class GroupsServiceImpl implements GroupsService {

    @Autowired
    private GroupRepository groupRepository;

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groupRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean addGroup(String name) {
        Group group = groupRepository.findByName(name);
        if(group == null) {
            groupRepository.saveAndFlush(new Group(name));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean changeNameGroup(String oldName, String newName) {
        Group oldGroup = groupRepository.findByName(oldName);
        Group newGroup = groupRepository.findByName(newName);
        if(oldGroup != null && newGroup == null){
            oldGroup.setName(newName);
            groupRepository.save(oldGroup);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean removeGroup(String name) {
        Group group = groupRepository.findByName(name);
        if(group != null) {
            groupRepository.deleteByName(name);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь подскажет как это реализовать, то просто хотелось бы пользователю отдавать результат получилось ли удаление, добавление, и т.д.

Comment: Можете вместо типа void у метода поставить тип инт, тогда будет возвращаться кол-во затронутых записей в базе. А дальше сравнивайте с 0.

Comment: И ставить `@Transactional` на объявления методов в интерфейсе расширяющем `JpaRepository` бесполезно.

Answer (score 2):

Если не возникает исключение то можно смело отправлять результат что операция добавления или удаления прошла успешно. В противном случае вам следует обработать ошибку которая указывает на то что операция не успешна.

Comment: Какое именно исключение то должно возникнуть? Потому что ловить Exception без указания определенного типа как-то не хочется.

Comment: Почему не хочется?

Comment: Ну я не преверженец ловить непонтно какие исключения, другим людям которые будут читать код, возможно это будет не понтяно

Comment: Если вы не знаете какие исключения вам нужно отлавливать, то вашим людям не нужно знать что именно вы хотите им сообщить и результат операции будет неопределённый.